# how to get data from database mysql in form select html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i was trying to show data from database into tag> select html. here is the code :

```
<?php
require 'koneksi.php';
$sql_select = "SELECT nama_supplier FROM supplier"; 
$hasil = mysql_query($sql_select);
  if(!$hasil) {
  echo "data not found ".mysql_error();
  }
  mysql_close();
?>
<div class="par control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="supplier">Supplier</label>
    <select name="supplier" class="uniformselect">
    <?php
       while($baris = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
       echo "<option value='$baris'>".$baris."</option>";           
       }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

the problem is, the output doesn't show the option value from database. the output only print 'array'. here is screenshot : [image](http://i57.tinypic.com/nc1kdt.png) . i know that it has to be something simple that i am missing but seriously i cannot figure it out. please anyone help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a row from the $baris variable which stands as an array

```
echo $baris['Coulmn you want'];
```

If you don't the variable $baris will be equal to something like that. You need to select which column you want.

```
([id]->1,[name]->'user',...,['email']->a@a.com)
```